# Android Studio becoming unresponsive

Tags: android-studio

Just moved from Eclipse to Android Studio a few days ago and everything seemed fine. Now after using it for a while I've noticed that it sometimes, seemingly at random, becomes completely unusable. The UI seems to hang for five or so seconds, then everything is alright for a couple of seconds, then hangs again. The "wheel" animation at the top right of the package explorer is spinning constantly too, but again this happens even when I've just left it for a while (No coding, no running projects etc...)

Update: Seems to start the wheel animation when I use the Full Screen mode and slowly gets more sluggish. Switching back to windowed mode after does not solve the problem.

Comment: I experience something very similar, running windows 7, first noticed it in android studio 0.2.6 and now in 0.2.7

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Android Studio. In my case I opened up Activity Monitor and force quit both Android Studio and adb. Post that on restart Android studio is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

I have found that closing and restarting Android Studio solved that problem.

In my case it became sluggish after about one week of intensive use without ever closing it. At first I thought it was because my app had grown too complex... The problem is probably caused by some memory leak inside Android Studio. After a restart it became ligthning-fast again.

Comment: I can't eve restart mine. I have to force-kill `studio64.exe` and hope no data get corrupted. Started happening after an update